# IOS vsnprintf implementation using NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, printf

I want to code vsnprintf function, using NSString.

This is my implementation of vsnprintf :

```
int my_vsnprintf(char *buffer, size_t count, const char *format, ...)
{
    int iRet;
    va_list ap;
    NSString *pnssBuffer=NULL;
    NSString *pnssFormat;
    const char *pcszBuffer;
    /* Format with NSString */
    pnssFormat=[NSString stringWithCString:format 
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    va_start(ap, format);
    pnssBuffer=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:pnssFormat arguments:ap];
    /* Copy to char * */
    pcszBuffer=[pnssBuffer cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    memcpy(buffer, pcszBuffer, count);
    iRet=strlen(buffer);
    /* Free */
    [pnssBuffer release];
    va_end(ap);
    return iRet;
}
```

When I call it with **char *** param, it works :

```
    my_vsnprintf(buffer, 256, "hello %s", "world");
NSLog(@"buffer = %s", buffer);
```

print correctly this : **buffer = hello world**

But when I call it with **wchar_t *** param, I only get fist character of **world**

```
    my_vsnprintf(buffer, 256, "hello %ls", L"world");
NSLog(@"buffer = %s", buffer);
```

print this : **buffer = hello w**

I don't understand why, any help for my function ?

Comment: The signature of `vsnprintf` is `int vsnprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, va_list ap)`, it takes `va_list` rather than `...`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, but it doesn't change anything about my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) in the "String Programming Guide", `initWithFormat:arguments:` and friends do not support the "%ls" format. In fact, the "l" modifier is ignored here.

There is a "%S" format, but that is for a sequence of 16-bit Unicode characters, so you cannot use it for `wchar_t` either.

**ADDED**

`wchar_t` is 4-byte Unicode (little endian) on the iPhone and the Simulator, therefore you can convert it to `NSString` as follows:

```
wchar_t *w = L"Hello world";
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:w length:4*wcslen(w)
    encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer.
Is there a way to create NSString with "%ls" format ? Without initWithFormat ?

Comment: @TheFrancisOne: Please see my updated answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Unfortunately, this code cannot work in my case, because I get a va_list which can be filled with "wchar *" or "int" or "char *" or ...

Comment: I do not know a built-in format function that works correctly with wchar_t. So the only solution seems to be that you parse the format string yourself and use va_start/va_arg/va_end to get the corresponding arguments and convert each of them to NSString, according to the format specifier. For wchar_t, you could use the code from my answer.